# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE - Replace multiple occurrences of the pattern with a substring

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

Is it possible to replace multiple occurrences of the pattern with a substring using *REGEXP_REPLACE* function in Oracle. I tried multiple permutation & combination of the regex expression, but somehow it didn’t work out correctly. Superficially it looks doable but not very sure.. any ideas or pointer to try out. Sample input/output below

```
INPUT_STRING =  SELECT @DATA:T.ID:ID@, @DATA:T.NAME:NAME@, @DATA:T.ADDRESS:ADDRESS@, @DATA:T.CREATED_DATE:CREATED_DATE@ FROM TABLE_NAME T
OUTPUT_STRING = SELECT T.ID ID, T.NAME NAME, T.ADDRESS ADDRESS FROM TABLE_NAME T
```

In essence, we need to achieve below in the fixed pattern

```
@DATA:xx.yy:zz@, where xx is table, yy is column name, zz column alias
```

1. Remove *@DATA:* from the beginning of string
2. Remove *@* at the end of string
3. Replace *:* with space

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924687/search-a-string-for-a-regular-expression-pattern-and-replace-each-occurences-as/48925355?noredirect=1#comment84858524_48925355

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like

```
select regexp_replace(txt,'@DATA:(\w+\.(\w+)):(\2)@', '\1 \2' ) from ( 
   select 'SELECT @DATA:T.ID:ID@, @DATA:T.NAME:NAME@, @DATA:T.ADDRESS:ADDRESS@, @DATA:T.CREATED_DATE:CREATED_DATE@ FROM TABLE_NAME T' as txt 
   from dual);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was struggling with the sub expression. I tried lot of combos.. but this was it, which I missed :)

Comment: Also, I tried another pattern - **@DATA:(.+?):(.+?)@**. Are there any repercussions with this?

Comment: Well, It depends of what you mean as repercussions. you specify good pattern ".+?" - will try to find "string" with least length and you may use it. with the same query `regexp_replace(txt,'@DATA:(.+?):(.+?)@', '\1 \2' )`

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this:

```
 replace(regexp_replace(str, '^@DATA:|@$'), ':', ' ')
```

Test:

```
select str, replace(regexp_replace(str, '^@DATA:|@$'), ':', ' ') 
from ( select '@DATA:xx.yy:zz@' as str from dual);
```

Comment: ^ - is begin of the string $ - is the end. If it in middle of line it will not work

Comment: correct, but  OP wanted to remove  only from the begin and the end

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it worked for the given pattern, however, when I am passing the entire string, it's not giving expected output.