# Search a string for a regular expression pattern and replace each occurences as a derivation of itself in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose following is my string:

```
 SELECT 'i want to increase those numbers 20 and 15' as testcol from
 dual;
```

I want to change those values `25` and `20` by adding `5`.
I tried with folloing code bt it's not working correctly.

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('i want to increase those numbers 20 and
 15','[[:digit:]]{1,3}', REGEXP_SUBSTR('i want to increase those
 numbers 20 and 15','[[:digit:]]{1,3}')+5) as testcol from dual;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/118)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH test(col) as(
  select 'i want to increase those numbers 25 and 250' from dual union all
  select 'i want to increase those numbers 999 and 99' from dual
)
SELECT col,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG(
                  REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.col, '(^.*?|.+?)(\d+|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 )
                  || (REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.col, '(^.*?|.+?)(\d+|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2 ) + 5),
                  ''
                ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL )
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.col, '(^.*?|.+?)(\d+|$)' )
       )  AS incremented_string
FROM   test t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/118/0)**:

```
|                                         COL |                            INCREMENTED_STRING |
|---------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|
| i want to increase those numbers 25 and 250 |   i want to increase those numbers 30 and 255 |
| i want to increase those numbers 999 and 99 | i want to increase those numbers 1004 and 104 |
```

Comment: This is works only for a one single row. But in my case first select statement also give many rows. Is there anyway to convert this solution for multiple rows?

Comment: @Nwn Moved the query to a correlated sub-query and it now works for multiple input rows.

Comment: @MTO This is working really well. but i cant figure out what really happening inside this code.

Answer (score 4):

Not regexp but it wokrs.

```
select  xmlcast( xmlquery('for $w in tokenize($text," ") return
    if(fn:matches($w,"[0-9]{1,3}")) then (xs:decimal($w)+$offset) else ($w)'
                passing 'i want to increase those numbers 20 and 15' as "text", 5 as "offset" returning content) as varchar2(1000))
  from dual;
```

Solution is looking for integers in text. For decimal internal regex should be extended.

`\d` and `[:digit:]` are not supported by xmlquery

Comment: If I live 1000 years, I won't be able to write something like that. I'm speachless.

Comment: This worked in Oracle 12 but in Oracle 11gR2 I needed to use `ora:tokenize` and `ora:matches` to get it to work.

Comment: @MT0 - I've tested it on 11.2.0.4.0. and its work. What i've found ora:matches supports [[:digit:]].

Comment: This is what we call harnessing the dark power of XML.

Comment: This solution is fine for single string. But I want to put many number of rows instead of the single string.

Comment: You can do this. Replace the string with the column name and dual with your table

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'i want to increase those numbers 25 and 250' col from dual),
  3  numbers as
  4    (select regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1) num_1,
  5            regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) num_2,
  6            --
  7            to_char(to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1)) + 5) num_1_5,
  8            to_char(to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2)) + 5) num_2_5
  9     from test
 10    )
 11  select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(t.col, '\d+', n.num_1_5, 1, 1),
 12                                              '\d+', n.num_2_5, 1, 2) result
 13  from test t, numbers n;

RESULT
-------------------------------------------
i want to increase those numbers 30 and 255

SQL>
```

Comment: This will not work for `i want to increase those numbers 25 and 250`.

Comment: Bah, details! :) Now it will, @MT0. Thank you!

Comment: this is not a generic solution